# Magento 2 Custom New Block without module

Tags: magento2, custom-block

I want to display special product on CMS home page in magento 2.1.3
What i did is :

**1) created block under app/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/Special.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Catalog\Block\Product;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context as CustomerContext;

/**
 * New products block
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.LongVariable)
 */
class Special extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct implements
    \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * Default value for products count that will be shown
     */
    const DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT = 10;

    /**
     * Products count
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $_productsCount;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    protected $httpContext;

    /**
     * Catalog product visibility
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
     */
    protected $_catalogProductVisibility;

    /**
     * Product collection factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;
   /**
     * Initialize block's cache
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('empty', 6)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('1column', 5)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('2columns-left', 4)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('2columns-right', 4)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('3columns', 3);

        $this->addData(
            ['cache_lifetime' => 86400, 'cache_tags' => [\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::CACHE_TAG]]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get Key pieces for caching block content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCacheKeyInfo()
    {
        return [
           'CATALOG_PRODUCT_NEW',
           $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
           $this->_design->getDesignTheme()->getId(),
           $this->httpContext->getValue(CustomerContext::CONTEXT_GROUP),
           'template' => $this->getTemplate(),
           $this->getProductsCount()
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Prepare and return product collection
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection|Object|\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection
     */
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        $todayStartOfDayDate = $this->_localeDate->date()->setTime(0, 0, 0)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $todayEndOfDayDate = $this->_localeDate->date()->setTime(23, 59, 59)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        /** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->setVisibility($this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices(
            $collection
        )->addStoreFilter()->addAttributeToFilter(
            'news_from_date',
            [
                'or' => [
                    0 => ['date' => true, 'to' => $todayEndOfDayDate],
                    1 => ['is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('null')],
                ]
            ],
            'left'
        )->addAttributeToFilter(
            'news_to_date',
            [
                'or' => [
                    0 => ['date' => true, 'from' => $todayStartOfDayDate],
                    1 => ['is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('null')],
                ]
            ],
            'left'
        )->addAttributeToFilter(
            [
                ['attribute' => 'news_from_date', 'is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('not null')],
                ['attribute' => 'news_to_date', 'is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('not null')],
            ]
        )->addAttributeToSort(
            'news_from_date',
            'desc'
        )->setPageSize(
            $this->getProductsCount()
        )->setCurPage(
            1
        );

        return $collection;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare collection with new products
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock
     */
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->setProductCollection($this->_getProductCollection());
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Set how much product should be displayed at once.
     *
     * @param int $count
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setProductsCount($count)
    {
        $this->_productsCount = $count;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get how much products should be displayed at once.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProductsCount()
    {
        if (null === $this->_productsCount) {
            $this->_productsCount = self::DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT;
        }
        return $this->_productsCount;
    }

    /**
     * Return identifiers for produced content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return [\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::CACHE_TAG];
    }
}
    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        parent::__construct(
            $abc,
            $data
        );
    }

    /**
     * Initialize block's cache
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('empty', 6)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('1column', 5)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('2columns-left', 4)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('2columns-right', 4)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('3columns', 3);

        $this->addData(
            ['cache_lifetime' => 86400, 'cache_tags' => [\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::CACHE_TAG]]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get Key pieces for caching block content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCacheKeyInfo()
    {
        return [
           'CATALOG_PRODUCT_NEW',
           $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
           $this->_design->getDesignTheme()->getId(),
           $this->httpContext->getValue(CustomerContext::CONTEXT_GROUP),
           'template' => $this->getTemplate(),
           $this->getProductsCount()
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Prepare and return product collection
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection|Object|\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection
     */
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        $todayStartOfDayDate = $this->_localeDate->date()->setTime(0, 0, 0)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $todayEndOfDayDate = $this->_localeDate->date()->setTime(23, 59, 59)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        /** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->setVisibility($this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices(
            $collection
        )->addStoreFilter()->addAttributeToFilter(
            'news_from_date',
            [
                'or' => [
                    0 => ['date' => true, 'to' => $todayEndOfDayDate],
                    1 => ['is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('null')],
                ]
            ],
            'left'
        )->addAttributeToFilter(
            'news_to_date',
            [
                'or' => [
                    0 => ['date' => true, 'from' => $todayStartOfDayDate],
                    1 => ['is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('null')],
                ]
            ],
            'left'
        )->addAttributeToFilter(
            [
                ['attribute' => 'news_from_date', 'is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('not null')],
                ['attribute' => 'news_to_date', 'is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('not null')],
            ]
        )->addAttributeToSort(
            'news_from_date',
            'desc'
        )->setPageSize(
            $this->getProductsCount()
        )->setCurPage(
            1
        );

        return $collection;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare collection with new products
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock
     */
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->setProductCollection($this->_getProductCollection());
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Set how much product should be displayed at once.
     *
     * @param int $count
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setProductsCount($count)
    {
        $this->_productsCount = $count;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get how much products should be displayed at once.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProductsCount()
    {
        if (null === $this->_productsCount) {
            $this->_productsCount = self::DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT;
        }
        return $this->_productsCount;
    }

    /**
     * Return identifiers for produced content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return [\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::CACHE_TAG];
    }
}
```

This is just copy of file vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/NewProduct.php

**2) Created file app/design/frontend/{vendor-name}/{them-name}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/special.phtml**

```
<?php echo "My Special Product Block"?>
```

**3) added cms content in home page**

```
<div class="special-product">{{block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Special" template="Magento_Catalog::product/special.phtml" }}</div>
```

Now i am getting error

> Error filtering template: Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Special::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context, instance of
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager given, called in
>   /www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php
>   on line 93 and defined in
>   /www/magento2/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/Special.php on
>   line 57

Can anyone suggest me what is wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with

> getCacheKeyInfo()

I missed to update cache key info as i have copied that file from core  and that's why it cause error.

I have updated key FROM

> CATALOG_PRODUCT_NEW

TO

> CATALOG_PRODUCT_SPECIAL

and it works.

Comment: please explain in detail Some one has flagged as low quality

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala updated.

Answer (score 2):

Try bellow block code

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Catalog\Block\Product;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context as CustomerContext;

/**
 * New products block
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.LongVariable)
 */
class Special extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct implements
    \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * Default value for products count that will be shown
     */
    const DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT = 10;

    /**
     * Products count
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $_productsCount;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    protected $httpContext;

    /**
     * Catalog product visibility
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
     */
    protected $_catalogProductVisibility;

    /**
     * Product collection factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $data
        );
    }

    /**
     * Initialize block's cache
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('empty', 6)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('1column', 5)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('2columns-left', 4)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('2columns-right', 4)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('3columns', 3);

        $this->addData(
            ['cache_lifetime' => 86400, 'cache_tags' => [\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::CACHE_TAG]]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get Key pieces for caching block content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCacheKeyInfo()
    {
        return [
           'CATALOG_PRODUCT_SPECIAL',
           $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
           $this->_design->getDesignTheme()->getId(),
           $this->httpContext->getValue(CustomerContext::CONTEXT_GROUP),
           'template' => $this->getTemplate(),
           $this->getProductsCount()
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Prepare and return product collection
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection|Object|\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection
     */
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        $todayStartOfDayDate = $this->_localeDate->date()->setTime(0, 0, 0)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $todayEndOfDayDate = $this->_localeDate->date()->setTime(23, 59, 59)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        /** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->setVisibility($this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices(
            $collection
        )->addStoreFilter()->addAttributeToFilter(
            'news_from_date',
            [
                'or' => [
                    0 => ['date' => true, 'to' => $todayEndOfDayDate],
                    1 => ['is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('null')],
                ]
            ],
            'left'
        )->addAttributeToFilter(
            'news_to_date',
            [
                'or' => [
                    0 => ['date' => true, 'from' => $todayStartOfDayDate],
                    1 => ['is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('null')],
                ]
            ],
            'left'
        )->addAttributeToFilter(
            [
                ['attribute' => 'news_from_date', 'is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('not null')],
                ['attribute' => 'news_to_date', 'is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('not null')],
            ]
        )->addAttributeToSort(
            'news_from_date',
            'desc'
        )->setPageSize(
            $this->getProductsCount()
        )->setCurPage(
            1
        );

        return $collection;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare collection with new products
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock
     */
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->setProductCollection($this->_getProductCollection());
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Set how much product should be displayed at once.
     *
     * @param int $count
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setProductsCount($count)
    {
        $this->_productsCount = $count;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get how much products should be displayed at once.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProductsCount()
    {
        if (null === $this->_productsCount) {
            $this->_productsCount = self::DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT;
        }
        return $this->_productsCount;
    }

    /**
     * Return identifiers for produced content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return [\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::CACHE_TAG];
    }
}
```

**Note:** after run bellow command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade –keep-generated
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```